# How to change Prometheus error message if token is invalid?

Tags: python, prometheus

I have a python file called `main.py` and I am trying to make a Prometheus connection with a specific token. However, if the token is expired, instead of the error message printing out `prometheus_api_client.exceptions.PrometheusApiClientException`, how can I get the error message to print our like `status_code: 500, reason: Invalid token` using a `try` and `except` block.

**Code**:

```
#token="V0aksn-as9ckcnblqc6bi3ans9cj1nsk" #example, expired token
token ="c0ams7bnskd9dk1ndk7aKNYTVOVRBajs" #example, valid token
pc = PrometheusConnect(url = url, headers={"Authorization": "bearer {}".format(token)}, disable_ssl=True)
try:
#Not entirely sure what to put here and the except block
except:
```

I've tested out a couple code in the `try` and `except` blocks and could not get rid of the long error from Prometheus. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting your pc variable in try and PrometheusApiClientException for  the exception. If that doesn't work, go to the source file and use whatever exception developers used while making authorization.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you catch that exception in a try/except block

```
try:
    # Interact with prometheus here
    pass
except prometheus_api_client.exceptions.PrometheusApiClientException as e:
    print('status_code: 500, reason: Invalid token')
```